# I was running the following PHP code using addition?

Tags: php

1. this is code:

   ```
       <?php
       $a = "4 fox and 3 cows"; // it is simple string
       $b = 22;
       echo $ab = $a + $b;
       echo "output::".$ab;
       ?>'
   ```

   output:
      only first index is being read
      26 
      what is the logic behind this..?
      instead I should get an error..

2.another example:

```
     <?php
        $a = "four fox and 3 cows"; // it is simple string
        $b = 22;
        echo $ab = $a + $b;
        echo "output::".$ab;
        ?>'
   output:
   22
   what is the logic behind this..?
```

Comment: we need some code in order to help

Comment: `$a` is converted to an int by truncating everything that is not part of a valid int. 4+22 = 26.

Comment: Why should you get an error? When you perform addition on a string, PHP attempts to turn the strings into integers first. In this case, it sees `4` at the start of your string, and discards the rest. (If there's no valid number at the start of the string, it becomes 0). So 22 + 4 is 26.

Comment: String concentration is with `.` pperatot

Comment: I'm trying to find a suitable dupe. Anyone got one?

Comment: String concatenation is in the manual : http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php - should have really been your first port of call IMO.

Comment: @everyone_talking_about_concatenation OP didn't say anything about wanting to concatenate the strings.

Comment: I love that these types of questions always get like 4+ answers...

Comment: @castis - low hanging fruit.

Answer (score 4):

You should look into [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php), php does it's best to accommodate the ability to transform type casting on the fly, using the + operator in php is meant for 2 numbers whether they are integer, decimal, etc.

Since strings don't have an integral value, when you use the + operator it will use the first part of the string that can make up a valid integer.

Since your example starts with `"4 "` it truncates everything else and turns the 4 into an integer making it 4+22 which is 26.

Comment: For this to be a good answer you should at least call it by its name: type juggling. It's an important thing to know in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Use the . operator to concatenate strings.

The + operator will convert the strings to numerics and add them

Comment: i dont think he's after string concatenation

Comment: It is not clear at all what that code is supposed to do. Just giving some pointers.

Comment: @iam-decoder that was what I was thinking, but couldn't possibly try to add the string as a number with another number. Probably was just an example or something.

Comment: Also, that is why I upvoted this and the above (just to counter the -1's.)

Comment: thankyou  @Evan Carslake for your support...

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to concat the number with the string, the operator in php is `.`, not `+`.

otherwise, why would you want to add a number with a string? What result did you expect? It seems in these case php parses the string to int, ignoring everything that comes after the number it can understand.

Answer (score 0):

`+` just converts your string to int, stripping everything unknown to a number.

```
"4 fox and 3 cows"
```

^^>
      everything there gets stripped, because a number can't be processed of `fox and 3 cows`, php reads the number from left to right and once it meets something weird, it stops.

Comment: Not exactly true. It's type juggling at work.

Comment: @John So? What's incorrect, still?